# What are the differences between C# namespace declaration with semicolon and curly braces?

Tags: c#

I have noticed two distinct methods of namespace declaration in C#.

```
namespace FirstProgram;
```

and

```
namespace FirstProgram {...}
```

I am looking for information on the key distinctions and purposes of the two types of namespace declarations in C#.

Example: with a semicolon ";"

```
namespace FirstProgram; // Why use semecolon (;)?

class Program
{
    //fields and methods
}
```

and

Example: with curly braces "{...}"

```
namespace FirstProgram // What is the difference in using curly braces ({...})?
{ 
    class Program
    {
        //fields and methods
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same. It is just a different syntax. The part with the semicolon is shorter and newer.

Comment: This is somewhat subjective, but my recommendation is to use file-scoped namespaces as it "gives you back" some horizontal space on your monitor for writing code. Also wanted to point out, don't confuse this with [top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Comment: Please clarify why information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace did not answer the question, ideally link your question to the doc and cite unclear parts (like "'File scoped namespaces can't include additional namespace declarations. You cannot declare a nested namespace or a second file-scoped namespace' is unclear because...")

Comment: What are the benefits of using file-scoped namespaces?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Namespaces without the curly braces are called `file-scoped namespaces` and were introduced with [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#file-scoped-namespace-declaration). Usually, a C# file contains only a single namespace. If the `File-scoped namespaces` are used, one level of nesting can be eliminated.

The only difference is, that when using `file-scoped namespaces`, you can't have multiple namespaces inside a single file.

Comment: Can the use of a semicolon in the namespace declaration in C# prevent the use of nested namespaces in other related files?

Comment: Since namespaces are on a per-file basis, I can't think of a reason why they should behave like that.

Answer (score 0):

[The form without the braces, *"file scoped namespace declarations"*, is a syntax sugar feature introduced in C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#file-scoped-namespace-declaration). They are equivalent.